# bash and zsh behave differently with this command, what could be the reason for this and is there a solution?

Tags: linux, bash, printf, zsh

Run in bash the result is:

```
printf "%s\n" {a..Z}{a..Z}
bash: bad substitution: no closing "`" in `a
```

It works in an interesting way when run in zsh, even though zsh is usually sensitive to commands with unusual input characters.

```
printf "%s\n" {a..Z}{a..Z}
aa
a`
a_
a^
a]
a\
a[
aZ
`a
``
`_
`^
```

Is there a solution for this just under bash, so that you don't have to fiddle with zsh separately for every execution?

Comment: bash and zsh are different shells, and trying to get the same non-trivial code working on both is usually an exercise in futility. Target one or the other, not both.

Comment: You nearly always have to fiddle with bash separately, for the same reason why you would not expect a program to be compilable by both Java and C. However, when you write a script, you always define inside the script (via the #! line), whether this is supposed to be bash, or zsh, or Perl, or whatever. So you don't have to care how a construct is interpreted in a different programming language.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> what could be the reason for this

Brace expansion happens before command substitution in Bash, while it's the other way around in Zsh.

> and is there a solution?

I do not think so, nothing as clean as just running zsh like `zsh -c 'printf "%s\0" {a..Z}{a..Z}' | while IFS= read -d '' -r a; do echo $a; done`.

Comment: I only thought of bash because not all shells include zsh.

So, in bash, I can only use it like this: `zsh -c 'printf "%s\n" {a..Z}{a..Z}'`